# How to find whether a path exists on a given tree?

Tags: python, tree

I want to implement a function something like this:

```
def is_path(t, path):
    """Return whether a given path exists in a tree, beginning
    at the root.
    >>> t = tree(1, [
             tree(2, [tree(4), tree(5)]),
             tree(3, [tree(6), tree(7)])
          ])
    >>> is_path(t, [1, 2])
    True
    >>> is_path(t, [1, 2, 4])
    True
    >>> is_path(t, [2, 4])
    False
    """
    if _______________________________:
    return False
    if _______________________________:
        return True
    return any([____________________________________________________________])
```

Helper functions:

label(tree) -> tree value

branches(tree) -> list of branches(also trees)

e.g.

```
    1
   / \
  2   3
```

label(t) -> 1

branches(t) -> [tree(2), tree(3)]

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing the `_____`s are there to indicate the parts you need to fill in? Have you got some code that's not working someone can help you with?

Comment: If the structure is a tree then there is a path between any two nodes--that is a consequence of the definition of a tree. For us to help you, you need to show us a complete code snippet that we can run and modify. Read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also explain in more detail what you are doing. Saying "I want to implement a function something like this" is far too vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the path to exist, at each recursive call, the head node must be equal to the first element in the path list. If it is not, then there is no match in the tree. If the head node is indeed equal to the first element in the list and the length of the input list is `1`, then a complete match was discovered. At each call with a path list of length  `> 1`, the function must be called on every branch:

```
def is_path(t, path):
  if t.head != path[0]:
     return False
  if t.head == path[0] and len(path) == 1:
     return True
  return any(is_path(i, path[1:]) for i in t.children)
```

---

```
class tree:
  def __init__(self, _head, _children=[]):
    self.head, self.children = _head, _children

t = tree(1, [tree(2, [tree(4), tree(5)]), tree(3, [tree(6), tree(7)])])
print(is_path(t, [1, 2]))
print(is_path(t, [1, 2, 4]))
print(is_path(t, [2, 4]))
print(is_path(t, [1, 3, 7]))
```

Output:

```
True
True
False
True
```